How can you find imaginary part of complex number when everything is in algebra?
This is simple code.
Im[3/(5 - 2 I)]

return $\frac{6} {29}$.
However,
Im[a/(b - c I)]

returns $Im[a/(b - I c)]$
In my opinion, it should give
$$\frac{a (b + c i)} {b^2 + c^2}$$
$$\Rightarrow Im[\frac{a} {b - I c}] = \frac{a c} {b^2 + c^2}$$
This is the code I use to find resonate frequency.
expr = Vx/Rp + Vx/(s Lp) == (VLO - Vx) s CGD;
sol = Solve[expr, Vx]
Av = Vx/VLO /. sol[[1, 1]]
Ag = Av /. s -> I w
Im[Ag]


Im[a/(b - c I)] // ComplexExpand since ComplexExpand will assume that all variables are real unless explicitly told otherwise.

Use the fact that, if $z=a+ib$ then $z^*=a-ib$ and $b=\frac{1}{2i}(z-z^*)$.  In your example:
z = a/(b - I  c)
zs = ComplexExpand[Conjugate[z]]
Simplify[z - zs]/(2 I)

